# Apply Google AMP (Accelerated Mobile Pages) to ASP.NET Core site

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, amp-html

I'm trying to create an AMP page with ASPNET Core MVC. I haven't been able to find many documents if any. For ASPNET, it was suggested to use `DisplayModes` to create a Google AMP Display. However, ASPNet Core doesn't support `DisplayModes` and I'm trying to figure a way to work around it. *Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!*

```
@model Models.Article
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!doctype html>
<html amp>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="canonical" href="/article.cshtml">
        <link rel="amphtml" href="/article.amp.cshtml">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1,initial-scale=1">
        <style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-moz-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-ms-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both}@@-webkit-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@@-moz-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@@-ms-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@@-o-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@@keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}</style>
        <noscript>
        <style amp-boilerplate>
          body {
          -webkit-animation: none;
          -moz-animation: none;
          -ms-animation: none;
          animation: none
          }
    </style></noscript>
    <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <article>
            <h2>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Title)</h2>
            <div>@Convert.ToDateTime(Model.PublishedDate).ToString("dddd, MMMM d, yyyy")</div>
        </article>    
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few ways to achieve something like this. One possibility would be to dynamically change your layout depending on the route, i.e. use template X for AMP or Y otherwise.

A more powerful solution would be the **view location expander**. This is also generally considered as a successor to the display modes. The view location expander is basically a mechanism that allows you to post-process the physical locations where the Razor engine will look for views. So you can use this to conditionally modify or expand the paths where your views are located.

In your case, you might want to change the behavior so that when accessing your site through AMP, Razor should first look for a `<view>.amp.cshtml` before falling back to `<view>.cshtml`.

In order to do that, you would have to implement [`IViewLocationExpander`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.razor.iviewlocationexpander). In [`PopulateViews`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.razor.iviewlocationexpander.populatevalues) you would have to detect whether you are within AMP mode or not; and in [`ExpandViewLocations`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.razor.iviewlocationexpander.expandviewlocations) you could then modify the view locations.

That could look somewhat like this (untested, as an idea on how to approach this):

```
public class AmpViewLocationExpander : IViewLocationExpander
{
    private const string ValueKey = "ampmode";

    public void PopulateValues(ViewLocationExpanderContext context)
    {
        // magic utility method that determines whether this is within an AMP context
        var isAmp = context.ActionContext.HttpContext.IsAmp();

        // persist the value on the context to allow the cache to consider this
        context.Values[ValueKey] = isAmp.ToString();
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> ExpandViewLocations(ViewLocationExpanderContext context,
        IEnumerable<string> viewLocations)
    {
        // when in AMP mode
        if (context.Values.TryGetValue(ValueKey, out var isAmpValue) && isAmpValue == "True")
        {
            return ExpandAmpViewLocations(viewLocations);
        }

        // otherwise fall back to default locations
        return viewLocations;
    }

    private IEnumerable<string> ExpandAmpViewLocations(IEnumerable<string> viewLocations)
    {
        foreach (var location in viewLocations)
        {
            // yield the AMP version first
            yield return location.Replace("{0}", "{0}.amp");

            // then yield the normal version as a fallback
            yield return location;
        }
    }
}
```

Once you have that, you only have to register the expander after the `AddMvc` call within your `ConfigureServices`:

```
services.AddMvc()
    .AddRazorOptions(options =>
    {
        options.ViewLocationExpanders.Add(new AmpViewLocationExpander());
    });
```

And then you only need to create your alternate views for AMP.

Comment: Hey, this is a great answer! I just wanted to add that I'm using `asp.net core 2.1` and I didn't find `ViewLocationExpanders` property in `MvcOptions`; Instead I configured my `ViewLocationExpander` by using `services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(o =>
            {
                o.ViewLocationExpanders.Add(new MyViewLocationExpander());
            });`

Comment: @MartinShishkov Oh, you are right, they are part of the Razor options. No idea why I thought they were part of MvcOptions. Corrected that in my answer, thanks! :)