# Applying Google AMP to MVC Core application (alternative to Display modes for MVC Core)

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, amp-html

I have an application which uses mobile views and desktop views as different HTML pages. Now I'm moving that to ASP.NET Core. I'm trying to create an AMP page with ASP.NET Core MVC.

Code:

```cs
public class AmpViewLocationExpander : IViewLocationExpander {
    private const string ValueKey = "ampmode";
    public void PopulateValues(ViewLocationExpanderContext context) {
        // magic utility method that determines whether this is within an AMP context
        var isAmp = context.ActionContext.HttpContext.IsAmp();
        // persist the value on the context to allow the cache to consider this
        context.Values[ValueKey] = isAmp.ToString();
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> ExpandViewLocations(ViewLocationExpanderContext context,
    IEnumerable<string> viewLocations) {
        // when in AMP mode
        if (context.Values.TryGetValue(ValueKey, out var isAmpValue) && isAmpValue == "True") {
            return ExpandAmpViewLocations(viewLocations);
        }
        // otherwise fall back to default locations
        return viewLocations;
    }

    private IEnumerable<string> ExpandAmpViewLocations(IEnumerable<string> viewLocations) {
        foreach (var location in viewLocations) {
            // yield the AMP version first
            yield return location.Replace("{0}", "{0}.amp");
            // then yield the normal version as a fallback
            yield return location;
        }
    }
}
```

I searched for this and implemented as in this link given: [Apply AMP using MVC Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53732980/apply-google-amp-accelerated-mobile-pages-to-asp-net-core-site?noredirect=1&lq=1), but it is showing this error:

> 'HttpContext' does not contain a definition for 'IsAmp' 
>   and no accessible extension method 'IsAmp' accepting a first argument of type 'HttpContext' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: "I searched for this and implemented as in the link given :- [Apply Amp using MVC Core]" What link? Also please format the top portion of your code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53732980/apply-google-amp-accelerated-mobile-pages-to-asp-net-core-site?noredirect=1&lq=1